# Apple watch series 2 barometer

Tags: ios, xcode, watchos, watchos-3

I try to check my iwatch2 barometer sensor(built in).
My environments are like this.
Xcode beta 8.1 + iphone6S(ios10.1) + iwatch2(watchos3.1)

This is my steps.
Projects > myBaro watchkit extension > info.list
add CoreMotion(for watchos 3.1)

in my source.
add coremotion
@import coreMotion.
And check altimeter(barometer) is enable or not.
[CMAltimeter isRelativeAltitudeAvailable]
This returns 0 - false.

I try same code with iphone6S. [CMAltimeter isRelativeAltitudeAvailable] returns 1 - true.

iphone6S and iwatch2 both have barometer.

I don't know why watchos returns false at iwatch2 case.

Is there anybody success to enable barometer?

Apple developer code-level-support answer my question. just link 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/SwingWatch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017286
But it is using phone motion information.

Answer (score 0):

Currently apple not support barometer functions on watch2. They will update and anounce when altimeter functions are working.